# JavaScript/Typescript return/break from a void method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a complicated  method with if else if else constructs in typescript.
Its a void method. 
How do i break from the method on some particular if condition so that other conditions need not to be executed. This helps me in avoiding the else condition ;I can keep on writing if

In Java this can be achieved using `return;` inside the void method.

Answer (score 7):

This is the the same in Javascript and Typescript as in Java : you just use a simple `return;`.

```
if (true) {
  return;
}

console.log('Never printed')
```

It is also the same in several other languages I can think of, like C, C++, C#, and many others with some slight variations on the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an empty `return` to exit the function execution:

```js
function test() {
  if(true) {
    return;
  } else if (true) {
    console.log('It will not be printed, because "return" is in first "if" statement');
  }
}

test();
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your value is returning an undefined type.
In typescript I check value vs null, but only in some types it works, for other types like Date I have to check with the undefined possibility too, like this:

```
if (this.creationDate === null || this.creationDate === undefined) { return; }
```

Comment: Just for information, the test `x === null || x === undefined` is equivalent to `x == null` (or also `x == undefined`, though I have seen more of the former than the later)